# Difference between Total Private Dirty,Total Pss,Total Shared Dirty in Android

Tags: android

I am just wondering what is the difference between Total Private Dirty,Total Pss,Total Shared Dirty. Though the explanation is on the [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html) it doesn't really make any sense to me.

getTotalPrivateDirty()
Return total private dirty memory usage in kB.

getTotalPss()
Return total PSS memory usage in kB.

getTotalSharedDirty()
Return total shared dirty memory usage in kB.

I would like to understand what are the piratical applications of these. I do understand PSS as I've read quite abit about it. But not the other two

Comment: Probably because you just explained what they return, but did not explain what you don't understand.

Comment: Not sure why people seem to thinks this is not a question. Maybe rephrase it. In any case, read this for extensive info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813

Comment: I'd like to know the answer. Which one to use while displaying memory usage for a user? Should we sum up all of them or what?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

public int getTotalSharedDirty ()

Return total shared dirty memory usage in kB.

public int getTotalPrivateDirty ()

Return total private dirty memory usage in kB.

public int getTotalPss ()
PSS (Proportional Set Size)

Return total PSS memory usage in kB.

Comment: Please explain in details all method term like dirty, shared, PSS and so on